# VSIX project template add inside vstemplate a new projectitem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates

I'm currently creating a Project Template in Visual Studio 2015 with an VSIX project and linked it with an C# class library project which should be my template if I'm creating a new project.

in my C# class library project in the .vstemplate file I want to add a folder and/or a file which I put by myself there. I add already the items to my project in VS.

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" OpenInEditor="true">Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
```

This is a part of the automatically generated .vstemplate file.

Now i want to add another file so I created a "UserControl1.cs" and want to add it like this:

```
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="UserControl1.cs">UserControl1.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" OpenInEditor="true">Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
```

But when I install the VSIX template I don't see my UserControl1.cs there.

Is there any problem in my .vstemplate file?

Thanks for your help.

Hannes. H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what a coincidence! I was facing the same problem....

But hey, I figure it out already: You need to add it to your .csproj file as well!

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs"/>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"/>
    <Compile Include="UserControl1.cs"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

For example in your case.

Cheers